# Ho do i call the next proxy from a textbox instead of using random next?

Tags: c#, winforms, random, proxy, webclient

Hello I have a question about calling a proxy from a textbox in c# webclient.
Right now I am able to get a random next proxy from a textbox but i would like to call the second proxy every time I made a request instead of random.

The code I'm using now is :

```
readonly List<string> proxies = new List<string>();

WebProxy RandomProxy
    {
        get
        {
            return proxies.Count == 0 ?
                null :
                new WebProxy(proxies[rnd.Next(proxies.Count)]);

        }
    }

proxies.Clear();
proxies.AddRange(txtProxy.Lines.Where(p => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)));

var proxy = RandomProxy;
var wc = new WebClient { Proxy = proxy };
```

After analyzing the request I've noticed that the proxies are changing but not how I would like to have the proxies called. So every request using the next proxy from the textbox.

Any one here who could explain to me how to change that? 
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Dennis

Comment: So, you want to each time call random proxy, exclude which has already been called?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to reach @MaKCbIMKo. Right now it is calling random proxies from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
// queue to get proxies in order started with random index
private Queue<string> sortedProxies;

WebProxy NextProxy
{
    get
    {
        if (sortedProxies == null)
        {
            var proxyCount = proxies.Count;
            var randomIndex = rnd.Next(proxyCount);
            // get proxies from random index to the end of the list
            var sortedProxyList = proxies.GetRange(randomIndex, proxyCount -randomIndex);
            // add proxies from start to the random index ('loop' for all proxies
            sortedProxyList.AddRange(proxies.GetRange(0, randomIndex));


            sortedProxies = new Queue<string>(sortedProxyList);
        }

        // dequeue the next proxy
        var proxy = sortedProxies.Dequeue();
        // enqueue proxy again for infinity loop
        sortedProxies.Enqueue(proxy);

        return new WebProxy(proxy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the script but when I analyze it and i'm running it in a loop. From the 10 proxies it ends up using 1 proxy after running the webclient. I've tried to remove your proxies.RemoveAt just to see if the proxies are called each time a new proxy from the nextline from the textbox, but its calling also random proxies. Is it possible to call the next proxy? instead of random. I'm sorry for the long question and hope i don't bother you with this. I really appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: So, you need just random select the first one, and then you need to go from this index by ascending?

Comment: Yes if that is possible to do select the first one and after every request get the next one and so one for each other request.

Comment: One more last thing i forgot to mention is because I'm using it in a loop is is it possible to start from the first line again after all the proxies are used?

Comment: Check again. I added the changes. If i understand you right - this is what you need.

Comment: Ok i've tried to add your script to my application but i get 3 errors :   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.WebProxy.WebProxy(string)' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'
System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  im not that good at coding so if you could help me with this?

Comment: You're right. I did some type and fixed it. Now it should work properly.

Comment: yes it is using each proxie now but it does not loop from the beginning again? If i have 6 proxies and i want to use the loop for 20 time it stops after 6 visits? How do i get more rep. to automaticly move to discussion chat?

Comment: Well, I modified the code to use infinity loop (again and again walk through 6 proxies). About more rep. - try to attend in SO activities.

Comment: Yes you are the best ;) @MaKCbIMKo really appreciate your kidness and willingness to help me with this.